# Pregunta acerca de los selectOneMenu Primefaces java en cascada

Tags: java, primefaces, select, if

EL día de hoy estaba desarrollando un selectOneMenu en cascada, para eso segui la documentación del Primefaces https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

Siendo así lo implementé en mi código para hacer una cascada de estos pero en 4 niveles:

este es el ubicacionBean.java:

```html
package com.nameEmpresa.integrado.bean;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="ubicaciones")
@ViewScoped
public class UbicacionesBean {
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data1 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data2 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data3 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();  
    private Map<String, String> paises;
    private Map<String, String> departamentos;
    private Map<String, String> municipios;
    private Map<String, String> barrios;
    private String pais;
    private String departamento;
    private String municipio;
    private String barrio;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializar(){
   paises  = new HashMap<String, String>();
        paises.put("Colombia", "Colombia");
        paises.put("Peru", "Peru");
        
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Cundinamarca","Cundinamarca");
        map.put("Boyaca","Boyaca");
        data1.put("Colombia",map);
        
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("depPeru1", "depPeru1");
        map.put("depPeru2", "depPeru2");
        data1.put("Peru", map);
        
        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("Mesitas", "Mesitas");
        map2.put("Viota", "Viota");
        data2.put("Cundinamarca", map2);
        
        map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("Tunja", "Tunja");
        map2.put("Garagoa", "Garagoa");
        data2.put("Boyaca", map2);
        
        map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("MunicipioPeru1", "MunicipioPeru1");
        map2.put("MunicipioPeru2", "MunicipioPeru2");
        data2.put("depPeru1", map2);
    
        map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("MunicipioPeru66", "MunicipioPeru66");
        map2.put("MunicipioPeru67", "MunicipioPeru67");
        data2.put("depPeru2", map2);
        
        Map<String, String> map3Barr = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map3Barr.put("barrio1Mesitas", "barrio1Mesitas");
        map3Barr.put("barrio2Mesitas", "barrio2Mesitas");
        data3.put("Mesitas", map3Barr);
        
        map3Barr = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map3Barr.put("barrioViota1", "barrioViota1");
        map3Barr.put("barrioViota2", "barrioViota2");
        data3.put("Viota", map3Barr);
       
        map3Barr = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map3Barr.put("barrioPeru666", "barrioPeru666");
        data3.put("MunicipioPeru67", map3Barr);
    
    }
   

    public Map<String, String> getPaises() {
        return paises;
    }

    public void setPaises(Map<String, String> paises) {
        this.paises = paises;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDepartamentos() {
        return departamentos;
    }

    public void setDepartamentos(Map<String, String> departamentos) {
        this.departamentos = departamentos;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMunicipios() {
        return municipios;
    }

    public void setMunicipios(Map<String, String> municipios) {
        this.municipios = municipios;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getBarrios() {
        return barrios;
    }

    public void setBarrios(Map<String, String> barrios) {
        this.barrios = barrios;
    }

    public String getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(String pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public String getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    public String getMunicipio() {
        return municipio;
    }

    public void setMunicipio(String municipio) {
        this.municipio = municipio;
    }

    public String getBarrio() {
        return barrio;
    }

    public void setBarrio(String barrio) {
        this.barrio = barrio;
    }
      
     
    public void onPaisChange(){
    
        if(pais != null && !pais.equals(""))
            departamentos = data1.get(pais);
       else
         departamentos = new HashMap<String,String>();
         municipios = new HashMap<String,String>();
         barrios = new HashMap<String,String>();
        
    
    }
    
      public void onDepartamentoChange(){
    
        if(departamento != null && !departamento.equals(""))
            municipios = data2.get(departamento);
      else
         municipios = new HashMap<String,String>();
         barrios = new HashMap<String,String>();
        
    }
      
      public void onMunicipioChange(){
    
        if(municipio != null && !municipio.equals(""))
            barrios = data3.get(municipio);
        else
         barrios = new HashMap<String,String>();
         
        }
    }
```

este es el .xhtml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
                       
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="paises" value="#{ubicaciones.pais}">
                            <p:ajax listener="#{ubicaciones.onPaisChange()}"  update="depar muni barrios"/>
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un Pais" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{ubicaciones.paises}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                 
                 
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="depar" value="#{ubicaciones.departamento}" >
                            <p:ajax listener="#{ubicaciones.onDepartamentoChange()}" update="muni barrios" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un Departamento" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{ubicaciones.departamentos}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
              
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="muni" value="#{ubicaciones.municipio}">
                            <p:ajax  listener="#{ubicaciones.onMunicipioChange()}" update="barrios"/>
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un Municipio" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems  value="#{ubicaciones.municipios}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
             
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="barrios" value="#{ubicaciones.barrio}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un Barrio" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems  value="#{ubicaciones.barrios}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

           
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

El problema estaba en que no  vaciaban adecuadamente los campos(marcados con los id´s = "depar","muni","barrios") cuando se ejecutaba el ajax del paisOnchange. Luego de mirar por horas me di cuenta de que al quitarle los corchetes al método del paisOnChange este funcionaba como yo quería. Estaba así:

```html
   public void onPaisChange(){
    
        if(pais != null && !pais.equals("")){
            departamentos = data1.get(pais);
       }else{
         departamentos = new HashMap<String,String>();
         municipios = new HashMap<String,String>();
         barrios = new HashMap<String,String>();
        }   
    }
```

Y luego le quite los corchetes y sirvió. quedando así:

```html
   public void onPaisChange(){
    
        if(pais != null && !pais.equals(""))
            departamentos = data1.get(pais);
       else
         departamentos = new HashMap<String,String>();
         municipios = new HashMap<String,String>();
         barrios = new HashMap<String,String>();
        
    
    }
```

Aquí es donde viene mi pregunta ¿No se supone que los 2 se deberían ejecutar de la misma manera? y ¿Por qué esos 2 bloques de código no son equivalentes?

Les agradeceria bastante si logran resolver esta inquietud que tengo :) .

Answer (score 0):

Una construcción *if-else* funciona así:

```
if (condicion)
   [bloque de código]
else
   [bloque de código]
```

(por supuesto, el *else* y el segundo bloque de código es opcional).

¿Qué es un bloque de código? Es:

- Una instrucción;
- Un conjunto de instrucciones agrupadas por llaves `{ }`.

Con

```
else
     departamentos = new HashMap<String,String>();
     municipios = new HashMap<String,String>();
     barrios = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

, sólo `departamentos = new HashMap<String,String>();` es parte de la ejecución del `else`; el resto de líneas queda fuera de la construcción *if-else* y se ejecutará independientemente de la condición. De hecho la tabulación correcta<sup>1</sup> sería:

```
else
     departamentos = new HashMap<String,String>();

municipios = new HashMap<String,String>();
barrios = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Con

```
else {
     departamentos = new HashMap<String,String>();
     municipios = new HashMap<String,String>();
     barrios = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
```

, lo que ejecuta el `else` es el bloque de instrucciones agrupado por las llaves, así que las instrucciones solo se ejecutarán si la condición es `false`.

Como nota aparte, lo explicado más arriba es una cuestión bastante básica de programación en Java. Si no tienes controlada la programación a nivel básica de Java, igual sería interesante que consideraras coger más soltura con ésta antes de añadir la complejidad de JSFs y otras tecnologías.

---

<sup>1</sup>Por supuesto, la tabulación no tiene ninguna influencia en como se compila el programa. Es útil solo para facilitar que el programador lea el código.